# SEO friendly Ajax navigation with fallback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm building a single page application with knockout js and .NET MVC 4 and have now come to the point where I need to get navigation work properly.
Is there a easy way to get SEO friendly navigation with history pushstate and fallback to old browsers?
This is a real simle example of how my page looks like:

```
<div id="Master">
   ... List of products ...
</div>
<div id="Detail">
   ... Product info ...
</div>
```

When clicking on a product I will load the product details and bind it to the Detail div with knockout js. I'm not loading a separate html file, everything is on the same page.

I'm thinking of a library called jquery address, but I'm a bit unsure about SEO and making urls work.
Entering product/xxx in the address bar wouldn't work. How do people do this, do they route all incoming requests to the "index" page with a parameter "product/xxx" which can be read by the javascript, which will load the correct content?

And what about fallback for users with old browsers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities I know of:

1. Hashtags. Your URL would look like so: http://funky.code.medina/your-app#/route/1
2. URL-Parameter. Your URL would look like so: http://funky.code.medina/your-app?route=1

There are libraries which handle that. E.g. it's included in AngularJS and there libraries dedicated only to these routing-problems like http://sammyjs.org/.

Fallback is option 2.

Comment: Hashtags aren't really SEO friendly though.

Comment: Depends. Google doesn't ignore it if it's in the correct format: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started